# GridSearchCV fails for own model class

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to use a regression model I have implemented in combination with the GridSearchCV class of scikit-learn to optimize the hyper-parameters of my model. My modelclass is nicely build following the suggestions of the scikit-api:

```
class FOO(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
def __init__(self,...)
    *** initialisation of all the parameters and hyperparameters (including the kernelfunction)***

def fit(self,X,y)
    *** implementation of fit: just takes input and performs fit of parameters.

def predict(self,X)
    *** implementation of predict: just takes input and calculates the result
```

The regression-class works as it should, but strangely enough, when I study the behavior of the hyperparameters, I tend to get inconsistencies. It appears one hyper-parameter is correctly applied by GridSearchCV, but the other one is clearly not.

So I am wondering, can someone explain to me how gridsearchCV is working (from the technical perspective)? How does it initialise the estimator, how does it run it over the grid?

My current assumption of the workings and required use of GridsearchCV is this:

1. Create a GridSearchCV instance  (CVmodel=GridSearchCV(MyRegressor,param_grid=Myparamgrid,...)
2. Fit the hyperparameter(s) via: CVmodel.fit(X,y). Which naively would work like this:

```
> Loop over Parameter-values
>          - create esimator instance with parameter value(and defaults for the other params)
>          - estimator.fit
>          - result[parameter-value]=estimator.predict
```

However, experience shows me this naive idea is quite wrong, as the hyper-parameter associated with the kernel-function of my regressor is not correctly initialized.
Can anyone provide some insight into what GridSearchCV is truly doing?

Answer (score 0):

After quite some digging I discovered, scikit-learn does not create new instances (as would be expected in OOP) but rather updates the properties of the object via the set_params method. In my case, this worked fine for the hyperparameter which is directly defined by the same keyword in the __ init __ method, however, it breaks down when the hyperparameter is a property of the static method set during the __ init __ method. Overriding the set_params method (which many tutorials advise against) to deal with this fixes the problem.

For those interested in more details, I wrote this all up in a [tutorial](https://dannyvanpoucke.be/building-scikit-learn-regressor-lssvm-en/) myself.